# Controlling a remote process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, controls

I'm connected to a server remotely. Now, I need to run a process, but the condition here is the process shouldn't terminate even though I had turned off my computer.

How to deal with this problem?

Relevant help is heart-fully appreciated..!!

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have a look at `nohup` and/or `screen` programs

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2nZdChQvAs

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- Run the script using [**`nohup`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)
- Run it through [**`screen`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)
- Run it using [**`tmux`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)
- Use [**`VNC`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) and run the script from within the X session.

Comment: I know about screen, but wondering how to use it correctly. Anyhow 'nohup' is a very good option than the others.

Thanks Jim for your help. :)

Comment: With `screen`, what you do is creating sessions, and then sending commands (the scripts you want to run) into those sessions.  Here's a quick reference: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference